# How can I get co-ordinates with drawing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am not using listener in my code then How can I get each co-ordinates points from drawing?

```
     function initMap() {
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
        zoom: 8
      });

        var drawingManager = new google.maps.drawing.DrawingManager({
        drawingMode: google.maps.drawing.OverlayType.MARKER,
        drawingControl: true,
        drawingControlOptions: {
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER,
          drawingModes: ['polygon', 'polyline']
        },

        circleOptions: {
          fillColor: '#ffff00',
          fillOpacity: 1,
          strokeWeight: 5,
          clickable: false,
          editable: true,
          zIndex: 1
        }
      });
      drawingManager.setMap(map);
}
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/31aey9mk/

Comment: @downvoter why did you downvote my question?may I know the reason?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've updated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/31aey9mk/2/).

Basically, you need to pass an array of `google.map.drawing.OverlayType`s of the type you wish you use. In this case, I've added a marker and polygon.

Then, you need to add an event handler in the `initMap()` method for capturing when the drawing has been completed:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(drawingManager, 'overlaycomplete', function (event)
{
    if (event.type === 'marker') console.log('Lat: ' + event.overlay.position.lat() + ', Long: ' + event.overlay.position.lng())
    else console.log(event.overlay.getPath().b);
});
```

Which grabs the event and the shape/marker which was drawn.

Comment: thank you soo much.How can i get exact lat and lng instead of `console.log(event.overlay.getPath().b);`

Comment: Well, a poyline/polygon has multiple points, therefore it's logical that it returns an array of latlngs. What you'd want to do, is iterate through the returned array and store them in whatever you need to.

Comment: But am getting undefined

Comment: omg!!! Is there any option to give extra upvotes in stackoverflow?I want to give you:-( really great!!!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help!